# Record type in salesforce

Tags: custom-object, standard-objects

[image]

Is it possible to create a Standard field in **Account** called **Account Record Type** with datatype as **Record Type**? if Possible How?

Comment: 1. We can not able to create new standard fields. We can create custom fields on Account object.  2. We already have a standard Record Type field on Account.

Comment: Navigate to Setup--> Accounts --> Record Types --> Click on New Button to create new Record Types for Account object

Answer (score 0):

There is already a standard field for recordtype.

Comment: In My Editon is Not showing how?

Comment: Its there in customize > accounts > Record Types.

Comment: I think you need to add some detail here.